# How to pythonicly improve a list comprehension

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, python-itertools, cheeseshop

What follows is a (working) attempt to compose tuples such that the i'th member of the i'th tuple is taken from the second tuple, with the remaining being taken from the first.

```
just_no =  ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire')
missing =  ('Caerphilly', 'Red Windsor', 'Camembert')
shop_window = tuple(tuple(no if i!=j else gone 
                          for i, no in enumerate(just_no)) 
                    for j, gone in enumerate(missing))
print(shop_window, "\nWhat a senseless waste of human life.") 
# (('Caerphilly', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire'), ('Gruyere', 'Red Windsor', 'Cheshire'), ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Camembert'))
# What a senseless waste of human life.
```

Much that it works, I'm wondering whether or not there's a more elegant solution, possibly using itertools?

Comment: Are they the only expected outcomes here?

Comment: I am confused about the naming, what does just_no and missing mean and why are they ordered in this specific way in the two tuples of shop_window? Just improving the names of these may make the code better understandable...

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen, this is merely illustrative - taken from the 'cheese shop' sketch.  The 'just_no' cheeses were given the response 'No' from the proprietor, whereas the 'missing' cheeses had some longer explanation..

Comment: @roganjosh, implicit to the question is that the size of the tuples is an unknown. The  print out is merely illustrative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner based on Python *indexing/slicing*:

```
just_no =  ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire')
missing =  ('Caerphilly', 'Red Windsor', 'Camembert')
shop_window = tuple(just_no[:i] + (gone,) + just_no[i+1:] for i, gone in enumerate(missing))
print(shop_window)
```

The output:

```
(('Caerphilly', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire'), ('Gruyere', 'Red Windsor', 'Cheshire'), ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Camembert'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking feature of tuples and write the following:

```py
just_no =  ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire')
missing =  ('Caerphilly', 'Red Windsor', 'Camembert')
shop_window = tuple((*just_no[0:i], missing[i], *just_no[i+1:]) for i in range(0, len(just_no)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with `zip`:

```py
just_no =  ('Gruyere', 'Danish Blue', 'Cheshire')
missing =  ('Caerphilly', 'Red Windsor', 'Camembert')
shop_window = tuple((tuple(map(lambda x : x[1][1] if x[0] == i else x[1][0], enumerate(zip(just_no, missing)))) for i in range(0, len(just_no))))
```

Comment: While it's interesting, I prefer the more elegant slicing method. Are there any significant benefits to this approach (over slicing) which I am unaware of?

Comment: Not really, except that the time complexity is more obvious on this one because there are two explicit loops, whereas the slicing hides the time complexity.